# Executing code from within a slider

Tags: jquery

My boss wants this functionality so I know it's convoluted. I'm essentially trying to have a slider within a slider. There will be a slider that moves divs in and out but also slider on each div that moves their own divs in and out. The Problem is the code on the inner div is not geting run because it isn't on the page when in loads. Anyway, can execute it after the slider moves?

I'm using [bxslider](http://bxslider.com)

Here's the markup:

```
<div id="slider1">

    <div class="food">

        <div class="inner_slide">

            <div id="slider2">

                <div class="fruit">Apples</div>
                <div class="fruit">Pears</div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="drinks">

        <div class="inner_slide">

            <div id="slider3">

                <div class="fruit">Water</div>
                <div class="fruit">Tea</div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Here's the jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    pager: true,
    randomStart: true
  });

  $('#slider2').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
    auto: true,
    controls: false,
    randomStart: true
  });

  $('#slider3').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
    auto: true,
    controls: false,
    randomStart: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Kishore - `$(function()` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function()`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this this works http://jsfiddle.net/2xNAp/ can you post a jsfiddle example of yours so that i can debug your code.

and why do you need a div which says inner slide? get rid of it and try

Comment: It looks like it's working because you have more than two elements in the upper UL. Make so there are only two and it doesn't work. Weird. My example only has two.

Comment: Do you have an idea as to why it doesn't work with just two slides?

Comment: @Thomas what do you mean by more than two elements in upper UL?

Comment: If you only have two or less <li> tags in either unordered list, it breaks. Take a look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/63srT/